# How can I fix this valgrind OS X 10.7.4 make error?

Tags: makefile, osx-lion, valgrind

I am trying to install valgrind in OS X 10.7.4.

I followed [these](http://valgrind.org/downloads/repository.html) instructions. Everything is fine until I run `make`, which gives me this error:

```
...
Making all in coregrind
(cd m_mach && mig /usr/include/mach/mach_vm.defs /usr/include/mach/task.defs /usr/include/mach/thread_act.defs /usr/include/mach/vm_map.defs)
2012-07-07 20:45:26.771 xcodebuild[82091:70b] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/DVTFoundation/DVTFoundation-580/Framework/Classes/DeveloperStructure/DVTPlatform.m:430
Details:  The Mac OS X platform is missing - cannot set a default platform.
Object:   <DVTPlatform>
Method:   +loadAllPlatforms
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x40010a220>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00000001023d4448 -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundation)
  1  0x00000001023d4304 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x00000001023735de +[DVTPlatform loadAllPlatforms] (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x000000010255985e IDEInitialize (in IDEFoundation)
  4  0x00000001028d374c -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool run] (in Xcode3Core)
  5  0x000000010236bd9f (in xcodebuild)
  6  0x000000010236bc28 (in xcodebuild)
  7  0x0000000000000005
/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild fails with 6 - Device not configured
/usr/bin/mig: line 174: : command not found
mig: fatal: "<no name yet>", line -1: no SubSystem declaration
make[2]: *** [m_mach/mach_vmUser.c] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I found [this](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=CAO4XC0vt4V25M-cGJ-t-f_8Ke7hnEkgSsHUu%3DAnSpqMsa-kZwA%40mail.gmail.com&forum_name=valgrind-users) post suggesting that it might be an issue with Xcode's path, but the path seems to be correct as per below:

```
$ xcode-select -print-path
/Developer
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I currently have Xcode 4.1 installed. I am downloading 4.3.3 now, perhaps that will take care of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my Xcode installation was old. After updating to current everything installed just fine.

Answer (score 1):

With Xcode 4.6 on OS X 10.7.5, I found that I had to run:

```
xcode-select /Applications/Xcode.app
```