# xcrun: error: developer tools not installed error during valgrind installation

Tags: c, xcode, macos, installation, valgrind

I'm trying to install valgrind on my Mac (10.6.8). I've downloaded the latest valgrind version, valgrind-3.8.1, unzip it and ./configure works fine. When I tried make, got this error message:

```
xcrun: error: developer tools not installed; download from http://developer.apple.com
/usr/bin/mig: line 174: : command not found
mig: fatal: "<no name yet>", line -1: no SubSystem declaration
make[2]: *** [m_mach/mach_vmUser.c] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I tried xcode-select (from this link: [How can I fix this valgrind OS X 10.7.4 make error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375207/how-can-i-fix-this-valgrind-os-x-10-7-4-make-error)) and got this message:

```
-bash: xcode-select: command not found
```

I guess I don't have xcode or xcode developer tools, I found both Xcode 3.2 and Xcode 3.2.1 Developer Tools in the apple developer site. I'm wondering which one should I install?

My feeling is this installation will solve the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: OK. I solved the problem after installing Xcode 3.2.1 and then update it to Xcode 3.2.6. T

Answer (score 0):

You can now get Xcode view the app store (free download).  Feature of this is that it will notify you of updates.  I think it's up to around 4.6.1 as of today, so what you're looking at is quite old.

Another alternative for valgrind is to get homebrew, and just do a brew install valgrind once it's up and running.